# Does the interpretation of " $\forall$ " differ in these contexts?

Tags: relations

I have a set $A= \{1,2,3,4\}$,

Reflexive Relation :

> If $(a,a) \in R \ \forall a \in A$ then it's a reflexive relation.

Note : **for all** $a \in A$

This means, $R$ is a Reflexive Relation as long as it contains **$(a,a)$ for all $a$** it doesn't matter what else is present in $R$.

Alright fine!

Symmetric Relation :

> $(a,b) \in R \iff (b,a) \in R$ **for all**  $ a,b \in A$

Again, note the **for all**

From here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation

But I have learnt that, $ R = \{ (1,2), (2,1) \} $ is also a symmetric Relation. Then what happened to "**for all**" part?

Clearly not **all** elements of $A$ were used, but it's still symmetric? However, for reflexive relation **for all** part in the definition is a game changer?

Similarly with transitive relation,  if $(a,b)$ and $(b,a) \in R \implies (a,c) \in R,$ **for all** $a,b,c \in A$ but we know $R= \{(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2) \}$ once again, I don't see the  **for all** part happening here.

This is as detailed as I could've gotten with my doubt. Please help!

Comment: In your example for symmetry, it is the case that $(a,b)\in R\iff(b,a)\in R$. There aren't any $a$ and $b$ for which that fails....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm not sure what you mean by that, but for comparison $R= \{(1,1),(2,2) \}$ is not reflexive because **all** elements of $A$ aren't used.

Comment: I meant what I said. Can **you** give me $a$ and $b\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $(a,b)\in R\iff(b,a)\in R$ is false for $R=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$?

Answer (score 5):

It is still "for all". The implication $$(1,3)\in R\iff (3,1)\in R$$ is true (as both sides are false), as are all other possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

**The $\forall$ means the same in all statements.**

Let's read the symmetric relation again, with some added brackets:

> $\Big[ (a,b) \in R \iff (b,a) \in R\Big]$ **for all**  $ a,b \in A$

An example, take the relation $R=\{\,(1,2), (2,1), (1,1)\,\}$:

$(1,2) \in R \Leftrightarrow (2,1) \in R$, that's true, since both sides lie in $R$.

$(1,4) \in R \Leftrightarrow (4,1) \in R$, that's true, since both sides do not lie in $R$.

Etc. We may conclude that $R$ is indeed symmetric.

For the **transitive** part, it is the same:
The statement

> $\forall a,b,c\in A: \Big[(a,b) \in R \text{ and }(b,c)\in R \Rightarrow (a,c)\in R\Big]$

means that for all $a,b,c\in A$, no matter what they are specifically, if $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are part of the relation, then $(a,c$) has also be a part of the relation.

Let's take $R=\{\,(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(1,4)\,\}$, which is indeed a transitive relation.

$(1,2)\in R$ and $(2,3)\in R$, so transitivity tells us that $(1,3)\in R$ aswell (which is the case).

Therefore $\Big[(1,2) \in R \text{ and } (2,3)\in R\Rightarrow (1,3)\in R\Big]$ holds.

$(1,2) \in R$ and $(2,4)\notin R$. $(1,4)\in R$, but that's not needed.

Therefore $\Big[(1,2) \in R \text{ and } (2,4)\in R\Rightarrow (1,4)\in R\Big]$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at "for all" is by translating it to something with the words "there exists."

For example,
$$ (\forall a \in A).((a,a) \in R)$$
is equivalent to
$$ \lnot(\exists a \in A).\lnot((a,a) \in R).$$

You can read this as: "There does not exist any $a$ in $A$ such that $(a,a)$ is *not* a member of $R.$"

The symmetric property can similarly be written as
$$ \lnot(\exists a,b \in A).\lnot((a,b) \in R \iff (b,a) \in R).$$

The expression $\lnot(P \iff Q)$ is a bit awkward to express in words,
but an equivalent statement is, "exactly one of the statements $P$ or $Q$ is true, but not both."
So the symmetric property is true *unless* there are elements $a$ and $b$ that have the relationship $aRb$ but do *not* have the relationship $bRa.$
Does your relationship provide any such pairs? No? Then your relationship is symmetric.

---

By the way, I would prefer to define the symmetric property this way:
$$ (\forall a,b \in A).((a,b) \in R \implies (b,a) \in R).$$
This turns out to be equivalent to the expression with $\iff,$
because anything that is true 
"for all $a,b\in A$" is also true "for all $b,a\in A,$"
and vice versa.
But I find the version with $\implies$ easier to describe and reason about.
In particular, converting it into the "exists" wording, the property becomes:

> There do not exist $a,b\in A$ such that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a)\not\in R.$

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate the answer given by **Martin**, I would like to emphasize on the validity of the biconditional $p\leftarrow\rightarrow q$:

$(a,b)\in R\leftarrow\rightarrow (b,a)\in R$ $\forall a,b\in A$ holds when

- Either both $p$ and $q$ are true or
- both $p$ and $q$ are false

  Your confusion arises due to the unawareness of the second case in which the pair $(a,b)$ is absent in $R$  for some $a,b\in A$.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I just read about biconditional statements. I was unaware of the second case.

Comment: My pleasure....@William.